# How to write user commands into TerminalExecutionConsole (Intellij Idea)

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a plugin in Intellij Idea which executes commands on thirdParty product side and prints the output of the commands afterwards. Everything should be done in self-written ToolWindow of Intellij Idea. The idea is to create an instance of ConsoleView with ProcessHandler.

For example:

1. I input "some command" in consoleView
2. Then I'm pressing "Enter" and command is sent to external API which executes this command
3. API returns the result
4. I take this result and print it to consoleView.

So the major question is: I already have an instance of consoleView (TerminalExecutionConsole) and I am able to print output of the commands into my consoleView. (Currently I'm using simple textField to write the command and button to send this command to external API). I would like to type commands directly in TerminalConsoleView and execute them by pressing "Enter". Is there any way to type commands into user-defined consoleView directly like it was done in Intellij Idea "Terminal" toolWindow?

I already tried GeneralCommandLine but it doesn't do what I needed.
Could you please advise any tips or share any example how to do this?

Explanation of the screenshot_1:

1. I typed "TIME" command into the text field
2. Click "Send" button
3. API processed the command and returned the result of execution.
4. I captured the output and print it to consoleView using notifyTextAvailable(message) function of processHandler object

[screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOFoO.png)

Comment: Can you mention the sample command and the screenshot as well ? Of what you are trying to exactly achieve

Comment: Hi @Harsh,
I added a screenshot and explanation of it to question description. My purpose is to "move" command typing to consoleView instead of textField